# FatFree prepare CSV for download, from database

Tags: php, csv, download, fat-free-framework

What would be the right way of getting CSV as a file download, prepared from a database table.
I would like this to happen on a button click.

Should I first make that `.csv` using standard way of doing it in PHP, then use `\Web::instance()->send()` in some route handler?

Answer (score 2):

`Web->send` expects a real file as input, so you'll have to go the standard PHP way:

```php
function dumpCSV($rows,$filename,$sep=',',$eol="\r\n") {
  header('Content-type: application/csv; charset=UTF-8');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
  foreach($rows as $row)
    echo implode($sep,array_map(function($cell){
      return '"'.$cell.'"';
    },$row)).$eol;
}
```

Also checkout [ikkez](https://github.com/ikkez/F3-Sugar/blob/master-v3/Sheet/sheet.php)'s `Sheet` class, which may help you rendering tabular data in Excel and CSV format.